# Facebook Chat user's API

Tags: facebook

Yesterday my friend's facebook was hacked and on same fb account, the hacker wrote me via fb chat and asked my credit card information for somereason. I was noticed as well and try to waste his time to detect his ip. I was traced network stats, Here is what i have. What do you think, which one could be his ip ?

(Deleted)

And what is the best action to take in this situation in order to catch him ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to catch him alive?

Comment: @techraf, is it matter  for you ?

Comment: You must've had twitter open as well since the highlighted ip address is an address for twitter, mate.

Answer (score 4):

If as you mention the "hacker" chatted with you via the Facebook website, then all you will get is the IP of a Facebook server somewhere in the cloud, which won't help you much.

Only Facebook could get you the sender IP, and I don't believe they would disclose such information.

Moreover, the attacker probably used at least one proxy, which would make your found IP pretty useless, unless you force the proxy to disclose the information as well, which will be extremely difficult.

If harm was made, besides contacting relevant authorities, not much can be done in your case. If the harm is high enough they might contact Facebook but many such cases are dropped (for example in Belgium where I live there are so many claims that, if it does not concern terrorism, pedophilia or money laundering, chances that priorities due to lack of budget will end up in no followup)

Comment: Law enforcement might be able to retrieve such information from Facebook with subpoenas (And depending on the proxy provider, get their IP-record too). Which is why contacting law enforcement is a better idea than trying to catch them yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys , i think too , the best idea is, contacting relevant authorities with my evidence.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen indeed, little update to my answer to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

Just hand your evidence over to law enforcement and facebook.

There is nothing more you should do; I strongly recommend [not trying to be a vigilante](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35738/how-can-i-punish-a-hacker). Cross reference the linked question for more information.

Additionally, you may not hold your breath on catching a hacker. They are likely to have taken good precausions.

Also, there is a fair chance that Facebook chat does not usually establishes peer to peer connections - so their IP most likely does not come up in your traces.

Comment: actually , i was asked to not catching him myself, asked to help the law authorities. But i agree, never try to be vigilante.Thanks for your recomendations.